# How to manage multiple viewcontrollers in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, hamburger-menu

I have been working on an app which has a slide menu which is there for an easier travel from vc to vc. [Here](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/03/ios-tutorial-make-interactive-slide-menu-swift/) I found a tutorial on how to implement the menu, but I have problem to switch vc's, bcs I don't know how to connect them without getting errors. What I have tried so far:

- All VCs to the menu and from the menu to the VCs. This worked, kinda, but I am getting the error: **...whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**
- From the menu to all VCs with unwind instead of a separate segue. Here I have a problem, where I don't know how to get to the menu... I tried to unwind it, but that also doesn't make sense, bcs I haven't performed a segue before it.

Here is how I have done the linking so far:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should download full example from [git](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/InteractiveSlideOutMenu). And review finished project carefully.

The error what you got related that in some time you remove your root view controller or try to push without any navigation controller.
The better way if you will use the similar scheme, where navigation controller is a root controller.
[image]

Comment: I have seen the full example and the only things that bothers me is that you have to go back go the blue view so you can access the slide menu. Instead of going back, the slide menu should be accessable from any viewcontroller.

Comment: Than you have 3 ways:
1) get access to the main menu from appDelegate (get reference from controllers stack) and send callback from any view controller
2) send notification for showing VC (not good practice)
3) relapse logic of vc navigations or change side menu I propose: https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu

Comment: I wouldn't like to use 3) because I want to have some understanding of how my GUI works. If 2) is a bad practiceI I am only left with 1). If it's not too much to ask for, could you maybe share some ideas on how to implement 1), since I am not that long into programming with Xcode(swift).